# fooC++ sizeof class member without instance

Tags: c++

Is this possible in C++?

I want to get the size of `member`, without using `bar`.

```
class foo
{
    bar member;
};

void test()
{
    new sizeof(foo::member);
}
```

Comment: What is the `new` for in your code? What are you trying to instantiate?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield Actually trying to the size of bytes, not a special case. Just curious.

Comment: @johannes Oh thanks. Did some research before posting here, didn't find that question. Should I close or delete this or what is usually done in these cases?

Comment: @Pacha: Are you sure the question linked by johannes is a duplicate of your question? It doesn't seem as though it is.

Comment: `sizeof(foo::member)` actually works.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yeah you are right.

Comment: @BrianBi I get: illegal sizeof operand

Comment: @Pacha perhaps that's because it's a private member. Also, what is `SomeClass`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
   public:
      typedef int MemberType;

      MemberType member;
};

void test()
{
   std::cout << sizeof(foo::MemberType) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   test();
}
```